# How to make actionlib service that depends on other message types?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm creating a new service using `actionlib`, where the goal is an external standard message type, `PoseWithCovarianceStamped`. Here is the `.action` file:

```
# Define the goal
PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose
---
# Define the result
bool succeeded
---
# Define a feedback message
float32 percent_complete
```

When I run `catkin_make` I get the error message:

```
CMake Error at [...] (message):
  Could not find messages which
  '[...]'
  depends on.  Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?

  Cannot locate message [PoseWithCovarianceStamped] in package
```

So then I said "oh, duh, of course I need that." I added `geometry_msgs` to my `CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED genmsg actionlib_msgs actionlib geometry_msgs)
add_action_files(DIRECTORY action FILES SetPose.action)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES actionlib_msgs geometry_msgs)
```

But I still get the same error message, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Here is a copy of my `package.xml` with comments removed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>set_pose</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The set_pose package</description>
  
  <maintainer email="edward.harvey@todo.todo">turtlebot</maintainer>

  <license>GPLv3</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib</build_depend>
  <build_depend>actionlib_msgs</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>actionlib</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>actionlib_msgs</exec_depend>

  <export>
  </export>
</package>
```

And here is a copy of my `CMakeLists.txt` with comments removed:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(set_pose)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED genmsg actionlib_msgs actionlib geometry_msgs)
add_action_files(DIRECTORY action FILES SetPose.action)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES actionlib_msgs geometry_msgs)

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293676/how-to-make-actionlib-service-that-depends-on-other-message-types?/) by [rahvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35098/rahvee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-09**:
Can you please update your question with your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [rahvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35098/rahvee/) on 2018-06-09**:
@jayess Updated. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sweet! I figured it out, thanks to @velveteenrobot in this discussion: [A string goal with actionlib](https://answers.ros.org/question/266734/a-string-goal-with-actionlib/)

I had to change my `.action` file to say `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped` as follows:

```
# Define the goal
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped pose
---
# Define the result
bool succeeded
---
# Define a feedback message
float32 percent_complete
```

---

Originally posted by [rahvee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35098/rahvee/) with karma: 30 on 2018-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1